# Jquery time spinner simplify

Tags: jquery, time, spinner

I wanted to use time spinner from the [JQueryUI example page](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time), but I dont need culture selector, I want it work only in german style (time select: 0-24). How could I convert it simply? Sorry for my poor english, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify your desired culture, then initialize the widget:

```
<p>
  <label for="spinner">Time spinner:</label>
  <input id="spinner" name="spinner" value="20:30">
</p>

$.widget( "ui.timespinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
      // seconds
      step: 60 * 1000,
      // hours
      page: 60
    },

    _parse: function( value ) {
      if ( typeof value === "string" ) {
        // already a timestamp
        if ( Number( value ) == value ) {
          return Number( value );
        }
        return +Globalize.parseDate( value );
      }
      return value;
    },

    _format: function( value ) {
      return Globalize.format( new Date(value), "t" );
    }
});

Globalize.culture("de-DE");
$("#spinner").timespinner();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/ysct6h6c/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works after I put the last two line into "$(function() {" and "});" (I dont know why :)

Comment: No probs. `$(function() {..});` just delays execution of your code until the DOM is ready. You could also put the code at the bottom of your page (e.g. before the closing </body> tag) and leave `$(function() {..});` out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is old, but i fell on this one while searching on my own, the easiest way was to use the start function in jquery. when using the spinner you can find the button pressed and then decide the action, this code will add or remove 30 minutes a pop and will return in a format "HH:mm"  you have to use moment.js plugin .

```
  $('#Timespinner').spinner({
      start: function( event, ui ) {
      if(event.currentTarget.className== 'ui-button ui-widget ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button-icon-only'){
        time = moment($('#Timespinner').val(),"HH:mm").add(30,"minute")
      }else{
        time = moment($('#Timespinner').val(),"HH:mm").add(-30,"minute")
      }
        $('#Timespinner').val(moment(time).format("HH:mm"))
        return false;
      }
    })
```